# C# How to get the "greyed" days of a month DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

In Windows 10 calendar, as an example, we find an grid of 7x6 days that represents each day of the month, but is obvious that no month has 42 days, so "overflowed" days, by any means, the days that show in the grid but isn't of current month is greyed out as a day of another month. Is there some easy way to get these days on C# with DateTime class?

For example, in 2020/08, the "greyed days" is: 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 (days of the previous month) and 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (days of the next month).

[In case that isn't clear, this is a screenshot showing the days that i'm referring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHwnI.png)

I couldn't find any question that relates my question.

**Edit:**

The best answer is by @ChilliPenguin, this is my implementation:

```
public static MonthGrayDays GrayDays(this DateTime time) {
        List<DateTime> before = new List<DateTime>();
        List<DateTime> after = new List<DateTime>();

        DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, 1);
        DateTime prevMonth = firstDay.AddDays(-1);
        DateTime nextMonth = firstDay.AddMonths(1);
        int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(time.Year, time.Month);

        for (int a = 0; a < (int)firstDay.DayOfWeek; a++)
        {
            before.Add(prevMonth.AddDays(-a));
        }

        before.Reverse();

        int count = before.Count();

        for (int b = 0; b < 42 - count - daysInMonth; b++)
        {
            after.Add(nextMonth.AddDays(b));
        }

        return new MonthGrayDays {previousMonth = before, nextMonth = after};
    }
```

This is an Extension method of DateTime class, it returns a custom class that returns the dates before and after the month, the class is implemented as follow:

```
public class MonthGrayDays {
    public List<DateTime> previousMonth;
    public List<DateTime> nextMonth;
}
```

To use the extension method, just call:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(2020, 8, 1);
foreach (DateTime date in now.GrayDays().previousMonth) {
    Console.WriteLine(date.Day);
}
Console.WriteLine("/");
foreach (DateTime date in now.GrayDays().nextMonth) {
   Console.WriteLine(date.Day);
}
```

Comment: You could figure this out with a knowledge of month lengths (remember February is complicated), some math and a handful of `if` statements (or perhaps a `switch`).  What do you plan on doing with this information - maybe there's an easier way to get to where you want to go?

Comment: @Flydog57 This is a way to do, but is a little bit complicated, nothing impossible. I'm using that to create a custom virtual calendar in my C# game using Godot, I could just show the days of the month, but to add more details I choose to add this feature

Comment: I think what it does is to just get the week in which the month starts for the first row, and then for ending is just continue getting days until you fill the 6 rows. Notice that this is dynamic based on the day you have set that the week starts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the DateTime and DateTimeOffset Structs you could calculate for the first day of the month's type of day using the [Day of week](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netcore-3.1) function. This would return an enum. If you convert the enum to an int(note, 0 = sunday, which does correlate with the windows calender) you would be able to loop back to get those dates. I would recommend using a List to store these dates, but I do not know your current situation :)

```
for (int a = 0; a < (int)FirstDay.DayOfWeek; a++)
        {
            graydays.Add(prevmonth.AddDays(-a));
        }
```

To get the dates after the current month we could get the count of the days listed, the number of days in the month, and the grid area(42 in this case) to calculate the amount of days after the month that we need to consider.

```
int count = graydays.Count();

    for (int b = 0; b < 42 - count - daysinmonth; b++)
    {
        graydays.Add(LastDayOfMonth.AddDays(b));
    }
```

Note, To get the daysinmonth, you need to use the DateTime.DaysInMonth() function, and to get the Last day, just add 1 month to the first day, and then subtract a day.

Comment: It's not very efficient to create whole Lists of DateTime objects just to count them.

Comment: @StevenGann The list of DateTime is an functional requirement, as is needed the references of the gray days

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an automatic solution, but the logic is simple enough to step through. The most important thing is the `DateTime.DayOfWeek` property. It returns a `DayOfWeek` enum value corresponding to Sunday through Saturday which can be cast to an `int` ranging from 0 to 6 accordingly.

Take your month and construct a `DateTime` object corresponding to the 1st of the month. Now take its `DayOfWeek` and cast to `int`, and now you have the number of grey days at the top of the calendar. Getting the number from the end of the month is equally simple. Build a `DateTime` object for the last day of the month and cast its `DayOfWeek` to an `int` and subtract from 6 to get the number of grey days.

If you need to dates for those grey days, start at first day of the month and subtract 24 hours to get the last day of the previous month. The grey days for the end of the calendar can be assumed to start at 1.